# Which Mars probe went to the highest elevation and which one to the lowest on Mars so far?

Tags: mars, probe, mars-exploration-rover

Considering Mars' mean atmospheric pressure of 610 Pa (0.088 psi) its "sea level altitude", how high went the highest probe/rover that ever successfully landed on Mars so far (respectively, what's the lowest atmospheric pressure a probe on the Martian surface has ever been in), and how low/deep the lowest one (or what's the highest pressure a probe/rover has been in)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I combed through [Wikipedia's list of Mars missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_Mars) and found all of the successful landers/rovers and included the Chinese [Tianwen-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianwen-1) though it has not landed successfully as of this answer. I got the elevations using [Google Earth Pro](https://www.google.com/earth/versions/#earth-pro) which has an option to view Mars and uses [MOLA data](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search?pmi-target=mars) from the Mars Global Surveyor. I cross-checked the InSight one with the official value from [2018 MARS INSIGHT TRAJECTORY RECONSTRUCTION AND
PERFORMANCE FROM LAUNCH THROUGH LANDING](https://trs.jpl.nasa.gov/bitstream/handle/2014/45976/CL%2318-7524.pdf?sequence=3) and it was correct:

| Spacecraft / Mission: | Latitude (°, N+): | Longitude (°, E+): | Elevation (m) | Visible on Google Earth Pro? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mars 3 | -45 | 202 | **1654** | no |
| Viking 1 | 22.27 | 312.05 | -3637 | yes |
| Viking 2 | 47.667569 | -225.715758 | **-4451** | yes |
| Mars Pathfinder | 19.098 | -33.25 | -3682 | yes |
| Spirit / MER-A | -14.5684 | 175.472636 | -1945 | yes |
| Opportunity / MER-B | -1.9462 | 354.4734 | -1373 | yes |
| Phoenix | 68.2188 | -125.7492 | -4128 | yes |
| Curiosity / MSL | -4.5895 | 137.4417 | -4447 | no |
| InSight | 4.5024 | 136.6234 | -2613 | no |
| Perseverance / Mars 2020 | 18.4446 | 77.4509 | -2564 | no |
| Tianwen-1 | 24.748 | 110.318 | -4040 | no |

Elevations are relative to the [MOLA geoid/areoid/equipotential surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Mars#Zero_elevation). Locations taken from Wikipedia for all (less [Tianwen-1](https://www.space.com/china-mars-rover-tianwen-1-landing-site)), modified for some to place exactly on spacecraft in Google Earth Pro.

Wikipedia also has [this nice graphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Features_and_artificial_objects_on_Mars):

[image: Wikipedia Mars graphic]

Comment: Thank you. Mars 3 doesn't have a sharp image, so the highest "proper" mission is Opportunity so far. However, I dunno what is used as "elevation" on Google Mars and on WP's map. Hopefully, both are according to pressure rather than vale-to-peak altitudes. But I guess they probably _are_ oriented on pressure altitude, or on mean radius which would be about the same.

Comment: @Giovanni they used to define 'zero-elevation' as a pressure but switched to a more consistent definition, see [Areoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Mars#Areoid) and  [Mars Zero Elevation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Mars#Zero_elevation)

Comment: So mean radius since 2001. However, as the Earth's sea level is defined at a certain pressure (29.92 inHg), the same method should be used on all celestial bodies with atmospheres. Or alternatively, the Earth's 0 altitude be defined as its mean radius.

Comment: @Giovanni you might find section 7.5 of [Mars Orbiter Laser Altimeter: Experiment summary after the first year of global mapping of Mars, Smith et al.](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/27881/1/SMIjgre01.pdf) interesting

Comment: @Giovanni [related](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26349/why-are-mars-northern-southern-hemisphere-altitudes-so-different)