# What's the lowest and the highest ever recorded atmospheric pressure by a Mars lander?

Tags: mars, atmosphere, probe, record

What is the lowest and what's the highest ever recorded air pressure on Mars by an (either roving or stationary) Mars landing probe?

As per the [answer in this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51988/which-mars-probe-went-to-the-highest-elevation-and-which-one-to-the-lowest-on-ma/51997#51997) of mine, it seems the highest pressure record would have been measured by Viking 2 or Curiosity and the lowest by either Opportunity or Mars 3; though the latter landed at higher elevation it failed before doing much science so I guess the measured record would be Opportunity's. However, surface pressure varies throughout the Martian year.

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 Thank you. How did you link to the answer itself? I tried it via the "Show activity" but it didn't work or I couldn't find the link.

Comment: You did successfully link to the answer (with every question or answer post there is a share option underneath that gives you a URL), all I did was change what text was included with the link to make it clearer that you are linking to the answer, not the question.

Comment: Also, consider registering your account, there are several *Giovannis* who pop up for a period of time then disappear ;). You get to keep your reputation and other such useful things if registered.

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 That's weird, my link should have gone to the entire question as far as I can tell. Whatever, thanks.

Comment: I will link to both (separately) for you

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 No, you don't have to, I'm glad it links to the answer which I wanted anyway.